What is that phenomenon when to defend an ideal one has to do the opposite of that ideal?
I'll give you an example.There is a person who believes in nonviolence. He believes it so much that he paints a board which says "nonviolence is the best way, violence is sin." And he is very proud to show it to everyone. He puts it on the door of his house. One day a passerby spits on to door and so the board which says nonviolence is the best way. Then the nonviolent person comes and he gets into fight with the guy who spat. They get violent after some heated exchange. So for a board which says nonviolence is the best way he resorts to violence.
I know this is an ironic example. But can you explain what is this phenomenon where the ideals (in this case, nonviolence) become valued so that to defend them you have to do the complete opposite of that ideal (in this case violence).
Another example can be given like people becoming rich by selling books that tell that all the world is maya and illusion. What is this phenomenon mentioned above? Has anyone written about it? If they have what is it called?

I am not talking about Nonviolence as specific .I am talking about ideals ,thoughts,concepts  turning into commodity.

The case of "making money by selling books that tell all world is maya and illusion" can be an example of opportunism.

The two examples do not really align, the second is just hypocrisy. But some ideals are self-defeating by their own logic taken to the extreme. What you describe is paradox of non-violence. There are paradoxes of freedom and tolerance as well. When fully unchecked, those lead to tyranny and intolerance.  Things taken to the extreme turning into their opposites  is sometimes called "enantiodromia".

No.sir I am not talking about Nonviolence or greed as specific.What I am trying to ask is .Sometimes ideals,thoughts  can be turned nto commodity .For instance a book. A board a poster etc .To protect to sell to buy to defend these commodities people can behave completely opposite of what these concepts or thought really say.Like doing violence to defend a board which promotes Nonviolence .I am just asking is this phenomenon Known.Or Is there any term or lets say writing of any one which can explain this .

@PrathameshThorat You may name this attitude "to pay lip service to an ideal".
